# How to add dependency jar when mvn package?

Tags: maven

I am working on scala project A which has dependency on B, generally, the `pom.xml` of A should have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId> ..info of project B <..>
    ....
</dependency>
```

However, I want to do some modification (test code) on B and build a new jar, thus project A does not depend on the B in maven repo but my local `B-with-dependency.jar`

How to do it? Firstly remove this dependency in `pom.xml`? And then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build `B`, give it a version number like `1.2.3-TEST-SNAPSHOT`.

Then you can reference that version in A.

Comment: put `B-1.2.3-TEST-SNAPSHOT.jar` into the same directory of `pom.xml`?

Comment: Don't copy around files. Build project B with `clean install` and then build project A on the same computer. Project A will read the artifact B from the Maven local repository.

Comment: I have installed it and now it is in `/home/.m2/repository`, the `pom.xml` could find the `jar` now, but when I try to package B, it said could not find artifact. But the default local repo is `/home/.m2/repository`. Which step I was wrong?

Comment: do I need to add local repository to my project `pom.xml`?

Comment: You do not need to specify it. Are there any files in the local repository that end with `.lastUpdated`? If so, delete them and when you `clean package`, you need to add the option `-U`,

Comment: I deleted the `.lastUpdated` files and added `-U` but it still tries to get the `maven-metadata.xml` and `-TEST-SNAPSHOT.jar` from remote repository and raise error as before

Comment: Maybe you should add the two POM files to the question. It looks like you are doing everything correctly.